# Using sprintf will change the specified variable

Tags: c++

I have a code,

```
char* bin2hexchar( const unsigned char& ibin, char* pbcd )
{
    sprintf( pbcd, "%02X", ibin );

    return pbcd;
}
```

The problem is, the value of ibin variable will change to zero value.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: This is not C code, as `ibin` is a reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your `ibin` is changing to a zero value in the caller to this function, the most likely explanation is buffer overflow.

I suspect it's probably because the buffer you're passing in as the second argument is defined thus:

```
char buff[2];
```

and `ibin` is adjacent to it on the stack.

The `%02X` format string requires *three* bytes, two for the characters and one for the terminating NUL character.

Even if that's *not* the specific case, it's still almost certainly buffer overflow. If so, please post the code that calls this function, along with the definitions for the relevant variables.