# sprintf in C resets the value of counting variable

Tags: c, printf

I'm having an issue with sprintf in C resetting the value of a counter variable when I run it. Here in a nutshell is what is happening:

```
int count = 0;
count++;
printf("%d\n", count); // count will equal 1
char title[7];
sprintf(title, "%.3d.jpg", count);
printf("%d\n", count); // count now equals 0 again
```

Is this normal behavior for sprintf?

Comment: Just make size 8, the contents won't fit because their size is 3 for count with leading zeroes + 4 symbols for ".jpg" + terminating zero.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`title` is too small, sprintf is writing beyond the bounds of `title`, and writing into `count`, corrupting its value.

Note that `title` needs to be long at least 8 bytes: 3 for `%.3d`, 4 for `.jpg` and 1 for the terminator `\0`.

As Grijesh Chauhan points out, you can make sure that you never write beyond the allocated size of the string by using `snprintf`, i.e.:

```
char title[8];
snprintf(title, sizeof(title), "%.3d.jpg", count);
```

Comment: so you should suggest OP `snprintf(  )`

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about the NULL indicator at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need more space in the string title: 3 digits+".jpg" = 7 chars, and u need one extra for '\0'(end of the string). Sprintf can change argument in a case such as this([Using sprintf will change the specified variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706086/using-sprintf-will-change-the-specified-variable))

Solution: change

char title[7];

to

char title[8];

Answer (score 0):

You problem is called [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). `sprintf` has no idea of the size of `title`, and write has much as needed, even if it exceeds the boundaries of your array. To fully understand, you also have to know that strings are terminated by a zero. This allows to find the end of a string, without prior knowledge of its true size. This extra zero takes the place of an extra character that you have to consider when dimensioning your buffers.

Consider also the use of [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) that ensures you are not going over the boundaries of your buffer.

Comment: The terminating `\0` is always appended in a call to `snprintf`. If you call it with `n` as the second argument and the length of the resulting string would be longer than n-1 characters, the remaining characters are discarded. As the nth character a `\0` is appended.

Comment: Of course, you're right... too long time not coded in C... :)